# how to use groupBy with F# linq-to-sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql, f#

I do

```
<@ linq.IncTXes 
|> Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.Query.groupBy (fun intx -> intx.RecTime, intx.ID, intx.str) @>
|> Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.Query.query
|> Seq.map     ^-^ fun sq ->
```

But F# to Linq can't understand / translate the type Tuple of 3 elements ... What can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tuples can't be translated to SQL. What you can do is do the group by in F# and not in the "SQL" (F# quotation) as shown below.

```
<@ linq.IncTXes @>
|> Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.Query.query
|> Seq.groupBy (fun intx -> (intx.RecTime, intx.ID, intx.str))
|> Seq.map     ^-^ fun sq ->
```

Comment: Yes ... that is what my question completely about. But that code is not a fix of my trouble for sure. Maybe the answer "You just can't do it" is the answer. But that is sad for me.

Comment: In Linq to SQL you can only use those "types" which represent the tables in database or primitive data types like int, string etc which are supported in SQL. As Tuple is something which doesn't fall into these categories hence you can't use it the way you want it

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't the tuple be surrounded by the brackets?

```
<@ linq.IncTXes 
|> Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.Query.groupBy (fun intx -> (intx.RecTime, intx.ID, intx.str)) @>
|> Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.Query.query
|> Seq.map     ^-^ fun sq ->
```